# laravel, convert stored date format in a model to use whereBetween

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to use whereBetween to get date interval, for created_date it works fine:

```
$data = Userorder::whereBetween('created_at', [$dateS->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00", $dateE->format('Y-m-d')." 23:59:59"])->get();
```

But I have another column name **order_date** where this column have the date in the format: **Fri Jan,24,2020** so I want to convert it to the format Y-m-d

```
$dateS = new Carbon($startdate);
$dateE = new Carbon($enddate);
$data = Userorder::whereBetween('order_date', [$dateS->format('Y-m-d'), $dateE->format('Y-m-d')])->get();
```

Model:

```
class Userorder extends Model
{
    protected $table = "userorders";
    protected $fillable = [
        'order_number',
        'product_id',
        'order_time',
        'order_date',
        'product_qty',
        'product_price',
        'product_totalprice',
        'totalprice',
        'product_instruction',
        'product_size',
        'storeinfo_id',
        'product_serve',
        'user_id',
        'user_distance',
        'user_address',
        'user_instruction',
        'office_name',
        'st_address',
        'order_state',
        'order_city',
        'order_zipcode',
        'gratuity',
        'suite_floor',
        'driver_ask',
        'phone_number',
        'paid',
        'isdelivery',
        'deliveredon',
        'show',
        'confirmed',
        'isonline',
        'houseaccount'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;
```

Comment: try to use attribute in the model   public function getFormattedOrderDateAttribute() {


return str_replace(',', '-',$this->order_date);

}

Comment: I tried this but not working

Comment: can you share the table schema?

Comment: I dont have it, but can I share the model?

Comment: I don't think you can get help without seeing the schema of that table. Do you know what datatype that column is in the database?

Comment: its a string not a date type

Comment: just for this query, no need to change whole column in DB

Comment: there must be away thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you're after you should be able to use Laravel's [whereRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-expressions) method in conjunction with MySQL's [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function ([mysql date format strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)):

```
Userorder::whereRaw('STR_TO_DATE(order_date, "%a %b,%d,%Y") between ? and ?', [$dateS->format('Y-m-d'), $dateE->format('Y-m-d')])->get();
```

This being said, if possible I would recommend updating your table (and related code) so that the `order_date` is actually a `date` column and not just a string.